# MVVMLight multiple instancekeyed-ViewModels with corresponding Views

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

it might be a dump subject-title, but I don't know how to summarize this problem.

First of all, I'm new to MVVM and MVVMLight.

I'm trying to create several instances of a specific viewmodel (e.g. GalleryViewModel) and display the corresponding data in a corresponding view, bound to a specific instance of a GalleryViewModel. So the user has (e.g) five GalleryViews open, while in the background each GalleryView must be bound to the corresponding GalleryViewModel.

Therefore, I call "GetInstance" of the SimpleIoC with a GUID as InstanceKey.

The problem is, that that way, the view doesn't get updated, when the data in the viewmodel changes. I found out, that this is only the case, when I instanciate the viewmodel with an instance key.

So I think, i have to link/bind that current view to that viewmodel with instancekey XY. But I don't know how to do it.

My "architecture" is like that: The MainViewModel calls the GetInstance(GUID)-Method. Within the MainView, a new UserControl gets displayed/created with the GalleryView. Its datacontext is bound to GalleryViewModel via XAML (but this might be the problem, because this binding can't know the GUID, so it might get bound to a wrong instance (?) and the DataBindings don't get updated.

Here is some code:

The ViewModelLocator returns only one instance (maybe that's the problem)

```
public GalleryMainViewModel Gallery
{
    get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<GalleryMainViewModel>(); }
}
```

From within the MainViewModel the "navigation" gets called (although my application lacks of a NavigationInterface (right now).

```
private void DoOpenTab(string windowname, string payload = null)
        {
            DockWindowViewModel window;
            string guid;            
            switch(windowname)
            {                    
                case "Gallery":
                    guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    window = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<GalleryMainViewModel>(guid);
                    window.ViewModelInstanceKey = guid; 
                    Messenger.Default.Send(
                        new NotificationMessage(payload), 
                        (window as GalleryMainViewModel).MessageToken);
                    DockManagerViewModel.AddDocument(window);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And the GalleryView (which is a UserControl that is being placed within an Avalon DockManager-Tab), looks like this

```
<src:PluginView
    DataContext="{Binding Gallery, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    <!-- just normal bindings. -->
</src:PluginView>
```

I hope, someone can help me a bit. I'm feeling really close to the solution, but I really don't know how to solve it completly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in your Locator

```
   public GalleryMainViewModel Gallery
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<GalleryMainViewModel>(); }
    }
```

And this is in your View

```
<src:PluginView
    DataContext="{Binding Gallery, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    <!-- just normal bindings. -->
</src:PluginView>
```

Then the VM created using the guid is **potentially** never bound to the view. It would depend on what happens when the notification message is recived by the view.

The above code tells the view to get its DataContext directly from the locator via the Gallery property. Which as you stated will be the same instance for all instances of this view.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I supposed. How can I change that behaviour? This is new to me. I think I theoretically know what to do, but I don't know how to do it in code. So in short: How can I bind a view to a specific VM-Instance? Do I have to do it in code-behind, or should this be done via Notification Message (from VM to V or from V to VM)? How would you do that?

Comment: There are a number of approaches depending on what the UserControl and VM do internally and what level of decoupling you want to achieve. 
If the VM is self contained and you don't need it after the UserControl is closed the simplest way would be to have the Locator return a unique instance each time by placing the Guid.NewGuid().ToString() in the Gallery property on the locator.

Comment: When the View has been closed by the user, the viewmodel can also be destroyed. In that particular case, the user "declares" not to use this vm-v-combination anymore. And if so, he can reopen that gallery (what creates a new vm-v-guid-pair. Correct? What could be the approch when the user want's to reuse/reopen the same pair again? How could a track the vm-v-pairs? This is new to me. Thanks so far. I'll try your solution later that day.

Comment: What i would probably consider for this would be a service class that I either gave the guid and it looked after which view went with which view model or gave it the VM and asked it to bind that to a view.
This post shows a simple example of the kind of strategy i am trying to describe.
[DialogService Example](http://blog.roboblob.com/2010/01/19/modal-dialogs-with-mvvm-and-silverlight-4/)

Comment: Just a quick response for now: Didn't had luck with your suggestion. But it doesn't mean, that you were wrong. I'll change my way of loading VM/V in a wpf app and take a look to your link (again) tomorrow. I'm sure, that this will solve my problem. Thanks so far!

Comment: **Solution** was to also remove the datacontext from the View since the View (PluginView) is a UserControl which inherits the datacontext. It now works, but it is unclear to myself where exactly the binding/datacontext comes from. MVVMLight does view-first (I think). I'm only creating a ViewModel with a guid and the xaml datatemplate for TabControl (here AvalonDock) connects the ViewModelType (GalleryViewModel) to the ViewType (GalleryView). But who/where does the DataContext-Binding between the specific view to the specific GUID-Keyed-ViewModel? May you help me one time to clarify? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not familiar AvalonDock so I'm not familiar with how that would interact with setting of the DataContext.
Possibly by adding the VM to the DockManagerViewModel document collection as you are it knows which view to associate it with and binds it?

Comment: That makes sense. Maybe that's the solution. I'll check that and if I know how it is done, I'll respond. But your comment makes sense... Thanks.